# How do you update form options using AJAX and php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, multidimensional-array

So i have a two dimensional array like this one:

```
$types = array(
    'type1' => array('AA', 'AB', 'AC'),
    'type2' => array('BA', 'BB', 'BC')
);
```

I want to create two form selections: 1 having the type selection ('type1', 'type2', etc.) and the second being the value selection ('AA', 'AB', etc.), except i want the value selection to automatically change options depending on the first selection.

I'm using PHP and the values are strictly from an array (not from a database).

Could someone help me with the AJAX and other code necessary to dynamically populate the second form selection?

---

To show you what ive tried, heres the code ive written so far:

**input cells:**

```
$settingCell = $this->Widget->input('sigtypes', array('id' => 'type', 'label' => '', 'options' => array_keys($model::$signalTypeOptions)));
$settingCell .= $this->Widget->input('sigtypevalues', array('label' => '', 'options' => $options));
```

**Javascript**

```
$this->Js->get('#type')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(
            array('controller'=>'utilities','action'=>'updateInput'),
            array('update' => '$("#options")', 'dataExpression' => true, 'data' => '{value: $this.value}')));
```

**UtilitiesController:**

```
public function updateInput($value = 0)
{
    $signalTypeOptions = $model::$signalTypeOptions;

    $this->set('options', $signalTypeOptions);
}
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? and that is not a two-dimensional array.

Comment: ok its a map to an array then, but its still an array in an array so i would consider it to be a two dimensional array for php. I havent tried much though because im really new to ajax and i dont understand the syntax really

Comment: I am working on a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer - it uses jQuery, AJAX and PHP.

please visit [here](http://danielabbey.co.uk/so/16019756/) for a working example.

I hope this is helpful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready
            (
                function()
                {
                    $('#select1').change
                    (
                        function()
                        {
                            value = $('#select1').val();
                            $.ajax  ({
                                        type: 'GET',
                                        url: 'ajax.php?type='+value,
                                        data: value,
                                        success: function(result)
                                        {
                                            $('#select2').html(result);
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1">
        <select id="select1" name="select1">
            <option value="">Please select a type..</option>
            <?php
                include('ajax.php');
                foreach($types as $type => $values)
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"$type\">$type</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select id="select2" name="select2" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then save the following as `ajax.php`:

```
<?php
    $types = array(
        'type1' => array('AA', 'AB', 'AC'),
        'type2' => array('BA', 'BB', 'BC')
    );
    if(isset($_GET['type']))
    {
        $type = $_GET['type'];
        if(array_key_exists($type, $types))
        {
            foreach($types[$type] as $arrayValue)
            {
                echo "<option>$arrayValue</option>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution that worked for my situation. Im using cakePHP,javascript, JSON, and AJAX.

```
<?php
$ajaxRequest = $this->Js
    ->request(
           array('controller' => 'Features', 'action' => 'edit'), 
           array('method' => 'get', 'success' => 'changeSelection()') );

$this->Js->buffer( $this->Js->get('#typeSelect')->event('change', $ajaxRequest));
?>

<script>
function changeSelection()
{
var value = $('#typeSelect').val(); // get the value selected in the first dropdown
var div = document.getElementById('sigType'); //div id is sigType
div.innerHTML = '';

    if(value >= 1 && value <= 3) // specifics for my situation, not important
    { 
        //get the array from php, convert to JSON and echo it for use in javascript
        var signalTypeOptions = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($signalTypeOptions) ); ?>;
        var selection = document.createElement('select'); // create the second dropdown

        div.appendChild(selection); // add the second dropdown to the division
        var i = 0;
        // loop through the array to fill the dropdown
        for(optionText in signalTypeOptions[value]) 
        {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = optionText;
            option.value = i;
            i++;
            selection.appendChild(option); // add the option to the dropdown
        }
    }
}
</script>
```